# Effect of Normalization On a Distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Let's assume that we have calculated some values proportional to probabilities for a special distribution(some hypothetical distribution other than normal distribution but we don't know which distribution it is). I want to use those calculated values as the probability densities for the distribution. To make the sum of probabilities equal to one, I normalize the calculated values (dividing each by sum of all). Would I lose the actual character of the distribution by doing this normalization. Because the name 'normalization' suggests that it would make the final distribution a normal distribution.

Comment: "Normalization" has nothing to do with the normal distribution (whose proper name is Gaussian, anyway). If your values are proportional to a probability mass function, normalization will convert them into a valid probability distribution.

Comment: I wasn't sure. Thanks for confirming this point. :-)